# Correctly allow word splitting of command substitution in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I write, maintain and use a healthy amount of bash scripts. I would consider myself a bash hacker and strive to someday be a bash ninja ( need to learn more `awk` first ). One of the most important feature/frustrations of bash to understand is how quotes, and subsequent parameter expansion, work. This is [well documented](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), and for a good reason, many pitfalls, bugs and newbie-traps exist in the mysterious world of quoted parameter expansion and word splitting. For this reason, the advice is to "Double quote everything," but what if I want word splitting to occur?

In [multiple](https://github.com/progrium/bashstyle) [style](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) [guides](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Variable_expansion) I can not find an example of safe and proper use of word splitting after command substitution.

## What  is the *correct* way to use unquoted command substitution?

#### Example:

***I don't need help getting this command working, but it seems to be a violation of established patterns, if you would like to give feedback on this command, please keep it in comments***

```
docker stats $(docker ps | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES)
```

The command substitute returns output such as:

```
container-1 container-3 excitable-newton
```

This one-liner uses the command substitution to spit out the names of each of my running docker containers and the feeds them, with word splitting, as separate inputs to the `docker stats` command, which takes an arbitrary length list of container names and gives back some info about them.

If I used:

```
docker stats "$(docker ps | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES)"
```

There would be one string of newline separated container names passed to `docker stats`.

This seems like a perfect example of when I would want word splitting, but [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) disagrees, is this somehow unsafe? Is there an established pattern for using word-splitting after expansion or substitution?

Comment: interesting Q, but I don't have docker installed. Please edit your Q to include a small sample of output from `$(docker ps ...)` that your are trying to "solve" quoting issues for. Good luck.

Comment: I'll give the breakdown of the command, I want to try to avoid it being the focus of the question, since I am asking a more general question about bash patterns

Comment: You're right, this is the case where word splitting is needed since you want to pass multiple arguments to `docker ps` command

Comment: My point is that it will be much easier for people to help you solve a specific problem, with actual data, rather than a verbal description that is open to multiple interpretations. That is to say, if it works when the output is `a "b c" d`, then it will solve my problem. Good luck.

Comment: I've edited the question to show output from the command substitution

Comment: Thanks, I'L'I, I forget to actually read koalaman's SC codes, I'm going to reshape my question a bit.

Comment: If the container names don't contain spaces then there's likely not going to be an issue. If you're unsure then use a loop, since that is what is recommended. The example of unquoted is more specific in the case they illustrate, whereas your example isn't reliant upon being in a single line i don't think.

Comment: Hm, may just create an answer then, thanks

Comment: It's not just spaces that are potentially a problem -- glob characters are also a problem. Let's say you have a container called `a[12]` -- if you have a file named `a1` or `a2` in your current directory, the name can be replaced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The safe way to capture output from one command and pass it to another is to temporarily capture the output in an array. This allows splitting on arbitrary delimiters and prevents unintentional splitting or globbing while capturing output as more than one string to be passed on to another command.

If you want to read a space-separated string into an array, use `read -a`:

```
read -r -a names < <(docker ps | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES)
printf 'Found name: %s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Unlike the unquoted-expansion approach, this doesn't expand globs. Thus, `foo[bar]` can't be replaced with a filesystem entry named `foob`, or with an empty string if no such filesystem entry exists and the `nullglob` shell option is set. (Likewise, `*` will no longer be replaced with a list of files in the current directory).

---

To go into detail regarding behavior: `read -r -a` reads up to a delimiter passed as the first character of the option argument following `-d` (if given), or a NUL if that option argument is 0 bytes, and splits the results into fields based on characters within IFS -- a set which, by default, contains the newline, the tab, and the space; it then assigns those split results to an array.

This behavior does not meaningfully vary based on shell-local configuration, except for IFS, which can be modified scoped to the single command.

`mapfile -t` and `readarray -t` are similarly consistent in behavior, and likewise recommended if portability constraints do not  prevent their use.

---

By contrast, `array=( $string )` is much more dependent on the shell's configuration and settings, *and* will behave badly if the shell's configuration is left at defaults:

- When using `array=( $string )`, if `set -f` is not set, each word created by splitting `$string` is evaluated as a glob, with further variances based in behavior depending on the `shopt` settings `nullglob` (which would cause a pattern which *didn't* expand to any contents to result in an empty set, rather than the default of expanding to the glob expression itself), `failglob` (which would cause a pattern which *didn't* expand to any contents to result in a failure), `extglob`, `dotglob` and others.
- When using `array=( $string )`, the value of IFS used for the split operation cannot be easily and reliably altered in a manner scoped to this single operation. By contrast, one can run `IFS=: read` to force `read` to split only on `:`s without modifying the value of IFS outside the scope of that single value; no equivalent for `array=( $string )` exists without storing and re-setting IFS (which is an error-prone operation; some common idioms [such as assignment to `oIFS` or a similar variable name] operate contrary to intent in common scenarios, such as failing to reproduce an unset or empty IFS at the end of the block to which the temporary modification is intended to apply).

Comment: I would like to mark this as the accepted answer, but I hesitate because your answer does not directly address the question. Please expand this answer a bit to directly address why the use of `read` is a safe and effective way to capture output from one command into an array of arguments for another command.

Comment: Does this answer your questions as amended?

Comment: great expansion, I'm going to add my own little edit and accept the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@I'L'I's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll) pointing to an [example of a valid exception](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046) to the "Quote Everything" rule, my code does appear to be a exception to the rule.

In my particular use case, using docker container names, the risk of accidental globbing or expansion is low due to the constraints on container names. However [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) provided a surefire and safe way to go about word splitting one command output before feeding it into the next command by reading the first output into an array using bash built-in `read` ( I found [`readarray`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) better suited my case ).

```
readarray -t names < <(docker ps | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES)
docker stats "${names[@]}"
```

This pattern allows for the output from the first command to be fed to the second command as properly split, separate arguments while avoiding unwanted globbing or splitting. Unfortunately my slick one-liner will perish in favor of safety.

Comment: re: `read` vs `readarray` -- consider `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a names` if they're on multiple lines; unlike readarray, that's compatible with bash 3.x, albeit with the caveat that it exits with a nonzero value if the input is not NUL-terminated.